# Using Betamax to record HTTP traffic from browser?

Tags: java, http, testing, browser, betamax

The betamax [documentation](http://freeside.co/betamax/#usage) seems to imply that the only way betamax can be/is meant to be used is through jUnit tests. But I hope that's not the case.

I want to use betamax to record the http traffic a user experiences through the browser, effectively doing some sort of mitm style setup to record requests the user made to a web-site, with the idea that I can start the browser up again in an off-line state, and replay those exact same requests. Does Betamax support this?

Comment: by browser you mean your own java implemented browser or something like firefox? if you are talking about firefox, this betamax thing won't help you, you need something like microsoft network monitor, or better specify a network adapter(not sure possible with java implicitly) on os

Comment: I mean like firefox. So Betamax, like I assumed, is just for java code?

Comment: Yes, betamax won't help you with this case, I don't think this is possible with java implicitly, find some native library/app about it.